# Get id from a Spotify JSON response with NewtonsoftJSON

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, json.net, spotify

i needed to get the "id" data from this JSON response with NewtonsoftJSON in C#:

```json
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "id": "0fa1a5aa7fdf4438a8082c993be1d9cd9bf0d32b",
      "is_active": false,
      "is_private_session": false,
      "is_restricted": false,
      "name": "DESKTOP-89E1DLU",
      "type": "Computer",
      "volume_percent": 26
    },
    {
      "id": "404bdc9492d312f104359d72c3ee55dd7f624120",
      "is_active": false,
      "is_private_session": false,
      "is_restricted": false,
      "name": "Fluent Spotify",
      "type": "Computer",
      "volume_percent": 100
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get always the **"id"** data from the block of data that contains the name of **"Fluent Spotify"**.

The Spotify Documentation playground for this is: https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-available-devices/

So can someone tell me how to parse this? Im new in C#. Thanks

Comment: Please take the [tour]. What have you tried so far? Please post your code and any errors you're getting. The Newtonsoft website gives good examples on how to deserialize JSON objects in C# [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [services](https://json2csharp.com/) out there that will generate c# classes for you from a json snippet. These do a pretty good job on your JSON example:

```
public class Device
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_private_session")]
    public bool IsPrivateSession { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_restricted")]
    public bool IsRestricted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("volume_percent")]
    public int VolumePercent { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("devices")]
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

One you have those classes you parse the json to the `Root` object

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

And then you can just use LINQ

```
var id = myDeserializedClass.Devices.First(x => x.Name == "Fluent Spotify").Id;
```

Note: The above assumes there is *always* an item with Name of "Fluent Spotify" - if there's not an error will occur. Use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` as appropriate if you need to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [Querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) and [Select Token](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) in newtonsoft

**try this :**

```
string json = @"{
  "devices": [
    {
      "id": "0fa1a5aa7fdf4438a8082c993be1d9cd9bf0d32b",
      "is_active": false,
      "is_private_session": false,
      "is_restricted": false,
      "name": "DESKTOP-89E1DLU",
      "type": "Computer",
      "volume_percent": 26
    },
    {
      "id": "404bdc9492d312f104359d72c3ee55dd7f624120",
      "is_active": false,
      "is_private_session": false,
      "is_restricted": false,
      "name": "Fluent Spotify",
      "type": "Computer",
      "volume_percent": 100
    }
  ]
}";

JObject spotify = JObject.Parse(json);
string id = (string)spotify["devices"][1]["id"];
// id = 404bdc9492d312f104359d72c3ee55dd7f624120
```

**Or try with Condition:**

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{
  "devices": [
    {
      "id": "0fa1a5aa7fdf4438a8082c993be1d9cd9bf0d32b",
      "is_active": false,
      "is_private_session": false,
      "is_restricted": false,
      "name": "DESKTOP-89E1DLU",
      "type": "Computer",
      "volume_percent": 26
    },
    {
      "id": "404bdc9492d312f104359d72c3ee55dd7f624120",
      "is_active": false,
      "is_private_session": false,
      "is_restricted": false,
      "name": "Fluent Spotify",
      "type": "Computer",
      "volume_percent": 100
    }
  ]
}");

JToken spotify = o.SelectToken("$.devices[?(@.name == 'Fluent Spotify')]");
var id = spotify.Value<string>("id");
```